# How to write/print in a Linked List?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I have this list right here and I have a doubt. am I storing it correctly in the list? Because I'm receiving the input from the user in my main function and then calling the inserting function, so I pass the struct to the function to store it into the linked list. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly because when I try to get the output the program ends instead of printing all data stored in the linked list...

I have declared this in my main function...

```
struct aluno info;
Lista* li = criar_Lista();
```

calling the function to store the data, passing the created list as li and the struct as info.

```
                scanf("%s", info.name);
                scanf("%d", &info.id);
                insert_List(li, info); // Calling the function to store the data inserted above.
```

Here's my inserting function which is called by the main function to store the struct in the list.

```
int insert_List(List* li, struct student info){
    Elem* no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    if (li == NULL || no == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    no->data =  info;
    no->next  = (*li);
    *li       =    no; 

    return 1;
}
```

The problem is, when I try to get the output, again, I call the function to print the list in my main function. Using, print_Students(List *li); Instead of the names and IDs, the program ends. Not errors are shown. am I storing it correctly?

```
void print_Students(List *li){
    if (li == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    Elem* no = *li;
    while (no != NULL) {
        printf("ID: %d\n", no->dados.id);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", no->dados.name);        
        printf("----------------------------------\n");
        no = no -> prox;
    }
}
```

Comment: It *looks* like `List` is a typedeffed pointer.

Comment: A testimonial to why hiding pointer types in `typedef` aliases is nearly *always* a terrible idea. It makes the code harder to read and maintain; not easier. Regarding your problem, *"I call the function to print the list in my main function."* - um.. what `main` function? The one you *didn't* include as part of your question ? Make a [mcve], including all declarations, definitions, and any/all input sample data required to reproduce your problem. And of course, run your code in a debugger if you really want to know were it pukes.

Comment: regarding: `if (li == NULL || no == NULL) {`  The head pointer should be initialized to NULL, so the parameter: `li` will be NULL on the first call, so nothing will be placed into the linked list.  BTW:  the `li` should be passed as a pointer to pointer so on the first insertion, the head pointer can be modified to point to the first node

Comment: Please post the definition of `List`.  Please post the declaration of the list head pointer

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", info.name);`   How many characters are in `info.name`?  When using the `%s` input format conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the buffer because this format specifier always append a NUL byte to the input.  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `Elem* no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));`  1) what is the definition of `Elem`?  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer. casting just clutters the code.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful,

Comment: There are LOTS AND LOTS of examples of how to code for a linked list on Stackoverflow.com  Strongly suggest doing a simple search.  Suggest using: `stackoverflow.com linked list`  as the search parameter